# Can't use \! when using the tipa package

Tags: math-mode, tipa

When using the `tipa` package, I am not able to use  `\!` as usual. I get a warning and the error

> Missing } inserted $!$.
> Too many }'s $!$

in the minimal working example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}

${}\!{}$    % Produces Warning: Command \! invalid in math mode
$\!$        % Produces above Error

\end{document}
```

How can I use `tipa` without those warnings and errors?

Answer (score 0):

In "TIPA: A System for Processing Phonetic Symbols in LATEX", accessible via https://www.tug.org/tugboat/tb17-2/tb51rei.pdf, it is written

> Finally there is one more option called ‘safe’, which is used to suppress definitions of some possibly ‘dangerous’ commands of TIPA.
>
> ```
> \usepackage[safe]{tipa}
> ```
>
> More specifically, the following commands are suppressed by declaring the safe option. Explanation on the function of each command will be given
> later.
>
> - \s (equivalent to \textsyllabic)
> - * (already defined in plain TEX)
> - |, :, ;, ! (already defined in LATEX)

and later

> **Special macros *, ;, : and !**
> TIPA defines *, ;, : and ! as special macros in order to easily input phonetic symbols that do not have a shortcut character explained above. Before explaining how to use these macros, it is necessary to note that these macros are primarily intended to be used by linguists who usually do not care about things in math mode. And they can be ‘dangerous’ in that they override existing LATEX commands used in the math mode. So if you want to preserve the original meaning of these commands, daclare the option ‘safe’ at the preamble.

After using `[safe]`, you cannot use -- for example -- `\textipa{[\*r]}` anymore, but instead you can use `\textipa{[\textturnr]}` instead.